# Error: failed to load module script the server responded with a non-javascript mime type of text/css

Tags: mime

soy nuevo en esto de la programación, asi que estoy creando un programa de lista de tareas, pero al cargarlo me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no tengo ni la menor idea de que pueda ser, agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias de antemano y saludos

Comment: Andres, serìa bueno agregaras como cargas el .css, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has incluido componentes.css como javascript

```
<script src="componentes.css"></script>
```

Eso no es correcto. El nombre del archivo con codigo javascript debe terminar con `.js`. Y archivos CSS se deben incluir con

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="componentes.css">
```

Comment: Gracias themylogin, ya logre correr el programa, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Un tipo MIME es una etiqueta utilizada para identificar un tipo de datos. Se utiliza para que el software pueda saber cómo manejar los datos. Tiene el mismo propósito en Internet que las extensiones de archivo en Microsoft Windows.

Entonces, si un servidor dice "Esto es texto / html", el cliente puede ir "Ah, este es un documento HTML, puedo representarlo internamente", mientras que si el servidor dice "Esto es aplicación / pdf", el cliente puede ir "Ah" , Necesito iniciar el complemento FoxIt PDF Reader que el usuario ha instalado y que se ha registrado como el controlador de aplicaciones / pdf ".

Los encontrará más comúnmente en los encabezados de los mensajes HTTP (para describir el contenido con el que responde un servidor HTTP o el formato de los datos que se PUBLICAN en una solicitud) y en encabezados de correo electrónico (para describir el formato del mensaje y archivos adjuntos).

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Fidel Fernandez, ya logre solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> failed to load module script the server responded with a
>   non-javascript mime type of text/html

se debe a que estas cargando incorrectamente el archivo .css

Debes cargarlo externamente de esta forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="componentes.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

---

De acuerdo al mensaje:

> "Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML
>   spec."

se debe a que al tratar de cargar un script, se requiere que el MIME de el archivo en este caso de Javascript debe estar configurado, pero en este caso el problema es que probablemente estas tratando de cargar un .CSS como si fuera un script:

```
<script src="componentes.css"></script>
```

lo cual es incorrecto.

si deseas cargar un .css externamente se debe realizar de esta forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="componentes.css">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, ya me funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso presenté el mismo problema publicando una aplicación de Angular 9 en un servidor de IIS 8. El error solo se daba en la maquina del cliente y no en la mía. La razón es que en mi maquina publiqué la aplicación indicando en el baseRef que la misma estaría dentro de un folder miFolder dentro del Site. En el caso del cliente no creó la carpeta miFolder dentro de un site existente, sino que creó la carpeta y un site que apunte directamente a ella. La solución en mi caso fue generar el publish sin especificar el baseRef (simplemente ng build --prod).

En pocas palabras, el error es concerniente a que el servidor no puede ubicar los archivos del proyecto según como el mismo fue compilado.