# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hola chicos estoy intentado desplegar mi aplicacion de angular en heroku pero al momento de cargar me tira este mensaje :
[image: error]
intente solucionarlo como lo encontre en este [error reportado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358704/error-failed-to-load-module-script-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-m), en el que decia que especificara el tipo de archivo que estaba intentado cargar y que verificara el orden en el que se estaban cargando, sin embargo esto no funciono para mi.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Clicknomics</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Material design admin template with pre-built apps and pages">
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="assets/icons/meteocons/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/icons/material-icons/outline/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FUSE Splash Screen CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
        #fuse-splash-screen {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #2D323D;
            z-index: 99999;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        
    ...
    </style>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!--Splash Screen -->
    <fuse-splash-screen id="fuse-splash-screen">

        <div class="center">

            <div class="logo">
                <img width="128" src="assets/images/logos/click.svg">
            </div>
            <!-- Material Design Spinner -->
           ...
            <!-- / Material Design Spinner -->
        </div>

    </fuse-splash-screen>
    <!-- / Splash Screen -->
    <app></app>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

cualquier tipo de ayuda para solucionar esto es bien recibida. Gracias

Comment: Este error a veces sucede cuando tienes tu aplicación en una subcarpeta y no en la raíz. Si es así tendrías que cambiar `<base href="/mi-subcarpeta">`.

Comment: Recuerda poner los errores por escritos.

Comment: deberia apuntar a donde esta todo mi proyecto ?... porque acabe de colocarlo => /dist/fuse/ y no funciono para mi

Answer (score 0):

resolvi esto modificando esto :

```html
 <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" type="txt/javascript" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" type="txt/javascript" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" type="txt/javascript" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" type="txt/javascript" nomodule defer></script>
```